# Converting all elements in a 2D Logical array into "Zero" except elements whose coordinates are given in another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm working with a 2D Logical array and i need to make all its elements zero, except some elements  whose indices are randomly given in another 2D double array. By randomly i mean that the  rows no. and cols no. are not in sequence.

consider:

```
        A=[1 0 0; 0 1 1; 1 1 0]; %The logical array

       I=[3 1; 2 3]; % indices of the elements i want them unchanged(stay 1)

        final_A=[0 0 0; 0 0 1; 1 0 0]; % expected output
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really just need a matrix the size of `A` where the elements in `I` are set to `true` and all others are set to `false`. You can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert from the row/column specified in `I` to absolute indices.

```
final_A = false(size(A));
final_A(sub2ind(size(A), I(:,1), I(:,2))) = true;

    0     0     0
    0     0     1
    1     0     0
```

This assumes that all elements of `A` specified in `I` were `true` to begin with. If this was not the case, then you will want to ensure that only the ones that were initially `true` in `A` are kept. You can do this using an element-wise [`and (&)` operation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html).

```
final_A = final_A & A;
```